# assumptions without "if" and so on

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Today in the newspapers I read

> Rodgers yesterday claimed had Sturridge  been with his club he would have been given extra time to recover in the same situation.

I don't understand how this sentence is built up. I understand that we are supposing but there is no *if* or *whether* and so on.

Comment: The word "*had*" introduces the subjunctive here.

Comment: That construction -- fronting a counterfactual hypothetical clause, and marking it as such only by subject-auxiliary inversion instead of using the complement marker _that_ and the hypothetical marker _if_ -- is archaic and acceptable only in main clauses (where it creates a stuffy odor of sanctity ill-suited to professional sport). In other words, it's ungrammatical as a [complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf) -- direct object of _claimed_ -- and shouldna been written at all. You were correct to notice the problem.

Comment: @John Surely this inversion is completely impossible in main clauses? It is equivalent to an _if_ clause, which is by definition a subordinate clause. Leaving out _that_ and not setting off the clause with commas makes it read rather heavy and clunky, but if that is rectified, the example quoted is perfectly grammatical to me. I'm also not sure about that “stuffy odor of sanctity”—game show-speak like “Your challenge, should you choose to accept it, is…” tends perhaps towards the formal side, but it's hardly stuffy.

Comment: @Janus: I think *"Your mission, **should** you choose to accept it..."* (and close copies thereof) are effectively facetious usages / set phrases. OP's example just seems like a dismal failed attempt to sound learned and authoritative, and replacing the deleted ***that*** does nothing to counter that. In my book, it's pretentious twaddle.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I probly mistyped. What I meant is that fronting a subordinate clause that way can only occur with a matrix clause, not a complement clause. The matrix clause is clause 1; the complement clause is the next down, clause 2; and the subordinate iffy clause is down below that, clause 3. In the example, clause 3 is moved to the front of clause 2, which is not a matrix clause. If the first 3 words were missing from the example, it would be grammatical because it would be fronted by a matrix clause (of course, you'd hafta know what _his club_ referred to in that case).

Comment: Another point of ambiguity is whether "his" and "he" refer to Rodgers in both instances, to Sturridge in both instances, to Rodgers in the first instance and Sturridge in the second, or to Sturridge in the first instance and Rodgers in the second.

Answer (score -1):

Buy a better newspaper. I think it should have been written like this:

> Rodgers yesterday claimed **that if Sturridge had** been with his club he
>   would have been given extra time to recover in the same situation.

"recover in the same situation" sounds strange to me. I think "recover from" would be better... but I don't know the context.